# Cookies aparece y desaparece

Tags: javascript

pues tengo una página en la que estoy poniendo política de cookies.
El problema viene que, al aceptarlas bien se guarda la cookie y tal pero al entrar a la web el mensaje de cookies aparece durante 1 o 2 segundos y cuando termina de cargar desaparece. No se de que manera ocultarlo y solo mostrarlo en caso de que no este la cookie.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  compruebaAceptaCookies();
});

function compruebaAceptaCookies() {
  if(localStorage.aceptaCookies == 'true'){
    cajacookies.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function aceptarCookies() {
  localStorage.aceptaCookies = 'true';
  cajacookies.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: estas usando `localStorage` para guardar si ha aceptado cookies o no? Porque esto es distinto de crear un cookie tal como dices en tu pregunta

Comment: Sí, uso localstorage para ver si el usuario habia aceptado antes las cookies, no para crearla.

Comment: He editado la respuesta. Probablemente deberás ponerlo como `display:inline`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un simple problema de lógica. Tal como lo has organizado tienes de inicio `cajacookies` como visible, deberías hacer los contrario `display:none` de inicio. Y si no ha aceptado, entonces lo pones visible.

Otra forma de hacerlo es poner la llamada de la función `compruebaAceptaCookies();` al inicio de la página, de manera que se ejecuta lo primero. Ahora se ejecuta dentro de `$(document).ready`, es decir una vez se ha cargado completamente la página, de ahí que se muestre la `cajacookies` durante unos instantes y una vez se ha cargado completamente desaparece.

**EDITO**

Desconozco la colocación del elemento `cajacookies`, pero para visualizarlo probablemente requerirás de un `display:inline` o de un `display:block`. En la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display) puedes ver el detalle.

Answer (score 0):

Vale muchas gracias. He ideado de otra forma, y he añadido en el CSS del div el display:none y cambiado el if.

```
<script>

function compruebaAceptaCookies() {
  if(localStorage.aceptaCookies != 'true'){
    cajacookies.style.display = 'inline';
  }
}

function aceptarCookies() {
  localStorage.aceptaCookies = 'true';
  cajacookies.style.display = 'none';
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  compruebaAceptaCookies();
});

</script>
```